# How to pass events from a non-Vue member object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-events

I have a component (`Foo`), one of whose data props is an instance of a class that's handling a lot of non-UI stuff (`Bar`). There will be some events within Bar that need to trigger behaviour in Foo. I'd like to wire them up in a way that respects the Vue data-flow model as much as possible. What would be the recommended approach for this? My naive solution would be to have some methods in Bar to set event handlers, so eg. in `mounted` I do `this.bar.onMyEvent(this.onBarEvent)`. Is this the best I can hope for, or is there a more Vuey way to do it?

```
export default {
  name: 'Foo',
  data: () => ({
    bar: new Bar(/* ... */)
  }),
  methods: {
    onBarEvent (data) {
      // do stuff with data
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the Computed Properties ?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: I have used them in general, but haven't thought of them for this purpose. Could you elaborate how you think they would help?